# Xcode cannot add a Mac OS X Server

Tags: xcode, git, osx-server, xcode-bots

I want to build a bot server for a project, but stuck with the config.

I config the Mac OS X server by:

1)switch on the Xcode service;

2)and create a hosted git repo.

Then I start up Xcode and find it cannot add the server, complaining that: "`The Xcode Service is disabled on this server. Contact the administrator for assistance.`", but I did switch on the service!

Am I missing something else?

Would anyone please give me a hand? I have googled for a long long time, and I just do the steps according to the Apple's docs, but the answers are not worked at all.
Thanks a lot!

[image: the picture containing the error message]

Comment: this machine is connected to the company's net, and not added to the local domain. but i set it to a static ip address from the company, so the local domain users could access it via the ip.

Answer (score 1):

i found a workaround. just as the x server and the xcode on one machine, so i just use the localhost ip address 127.0.0.1 instead, and it works.